# Scrapy: How to access the custom, CLI passed settings from the __init__() method of a spider class?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline, scrapy-settings

I need to access the custom settings passed from the CLI using:

`-s SETTING_NAME="SETTING_VAL"`
**from the __init__() method of the spider class**.

`get_project_settings()` allows me to access only the static settings.

The docs explain how you can access those custom settings by from a pipeline setting up a new pipeline through:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    settings = crawler.settings
```

But is there any way to access them from the `__init__()` spider method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`settings.get`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.settings.BaseSettings.get) e.g.

```
print(self.settings.get('SETTING_NAME'))
```

will print

```
SETTING_VAL
```

If you want to access a setting in your spider `__init__` you have a couple of options. If you command-line options is just a `spider` argument, use `-a` instead of `-s`. If for some reason you need to access an actual setting in your spider `__init__` then you have to override the `from_crawler` `classmethod` as described in the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#how-to-access-settings).

Here is an example:

```
import scrapy

class ArgsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_spider"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('kwargs =', kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = cls(
            *args,
            my_setting=crawler.settings.get("MY_SETTING"),
            **kwargs
        )
        spider._set_crawler(crawler)
        return spider
```

run with e.g. `scrapy runspider args_spider.py -s MY_SETTING=hello,world!` and you will see your setting in the `kwargs` dict. You can of course get other settings this way too

Comment: An instance of ```BaseSettings``` gives me empty values. An instance of ```Settings``` still contains only the project static settings and not the ones passed through the CLI.

Comment: @NikolayShindarov where are you trying to access the settings? Please post what you are trying your question.

Comment: @tomjin Inside the ```Spider``` inherited class. Sorry, thought it was clear enough, changed the title now.

Comment: @NikolayShindarov that is clear. Can you add your spider code? Are you accessing them in the `__init__` function? The answer here works fine for getting settings elsewhere in the spider.

Comment: It does not work, I tried it also inside ```parse()```. Please, note the details of my question: I need the custom settings passed via the CLI using the ```-s``` parameter. The code from your answer loads only the static settings, regardless of where it is called - inside ```__init__()``` or in another method.

Comment: @NikolayShindarov it does work I’ve tested it. Please post the exact line you are using.

Comment: CLI: ```scrapy crawl -a somearg="someval" -s my_arg="X"``` Code:
    ```def parse(self, response):
        from scrapy.settings import Settings, BaseSettings
        sett1 = Settings()
        sett2 = BaseSettings()
        __import__('pprint').pprint(dict(sett1))
        print(sett1.get('my_arg'))
        __import__('pprint').pprint(dict(sett2))
        print(sett2.get('my_arg'))```
Both of them give me ```None```

Comment: @NikolayShindarov you don’t need to do any of that. Just do `def parse(self, response): print(self.settings.get('my_arg'))`. Try that and let me know.

Comment: That indeed works, thanks. However, my issue is still not resolved at it seems it does not work inside ```__init__()``` or inside a method called by ```__init__()```. I upvoted your answer and modified the specifications of my questions, the issue remains unresolved.

Comment: @NikolayShindarov I've updated my answer to also answer your new question

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do it meanwhile exactly using the from_crawler factory method. I accepted your answer and added mine as I needed some more tweaks in my situation to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

None of the responses work when using `CrawlSpider`, because some methods such as [`_follow_links`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/7b1bc9b7fefce60c51f89f7ed47e1d172e43b2a7/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py#L138) will be missing.

The following code works:

```py
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    spider = super().from_crawler(
            crawler,
            *args,
            some_arg=crawler.settings.get("SOME_ARG"), **kwargs
    )
    return spider
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @tomjn works, I just want to point out that if you are using extensions or middlewares which need the crawler object, you need to alter his factory method this way:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = cls(
        *args,
        my_setting=crawler.settings.get("MY_SETTING"),
        **kwargs
    )
    obj.crawler = crawler
    return obj
```

Not sure if you need to do it if you instantiate the spider itself, but in my case, when I was inheriting it, my script would crash complaining about missing crawler attribute until I did it this way.